# Why is it not possible to delete IE addons from the IE interface?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons

You can disable but you can't delete them *from the "Manage addons" dialog*.

In IE 7 there was a delete button but I've never seen it enabled, in IE 8 I don't see the button at all.

My guess would be that IE addons are registered as COM components and you cannot track who uses that component besides IE itself so it would be unsafe to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you actually can.

Go to the Addons Manager, select the addon, and hit 'More Information'. A new dialog will popup, here you can hit 'Remove'. Does not work on all addons, though.

Source: [Microsoft IE FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Internet-Explorer-add-ons-frequently-asked-questions)   : 'Can I delete Add-ons or ActiveX controls?'

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now I know where the delete button is in IE 8 :) But still for the most of my addons it is disabled (except for the flash plugin) and many of them are not preinstalled ones, so I wonder if that's a decision made by the addon providers whether to allow to remove their addons trough this 'Manage Add-ons' dialog.

Comment: I guess so, yes. i have no idea how else you should remove them, if you can't remove them from IE or Control Panel. I guess the only step you could take, is moving to another browser; or reinstalling IE.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes addons (or plugins) get installed as separates programs (ie: flash plugin) you can uninstall them from Control Panel (add/remove programs).

Comment: Yeah, there are some. Google toolbar and Google Chrome Frame is also in this category. But some plugins don't show up in "add/remove programs".

Comment: what plugin you are trying to uninstall ?